# Whats exactly wrong with my eclipse?

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse linux package 32 bit.`eclipse-jee-oxygen-R-linux-gtk.tar.gz` I right click and extracted it. And I tried to open eclipse in so many design, nothing worked,. Searched a ton in google and here. No luck.  I'm using ubtuntu mate on raspberry pi3.
[image]

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install eclipse`

Comment: @AndroidDev This will install eclipse 3.8 old version. Doesn't have eclipse market space.

Comment: Well you need the ARM version of Eclipse, not the x86 version

Comment: @AndroidDev sounds like an answer (*wink wink*). Looks like it's an architecture conflict from the output.

Comment: @AndroidDev  I'll try to search arm version of eclipse. If not found, then there is no way to run eclipse right? Eclipse is running on JVM right? I'm not sure about eclipse architecture.

Comment: Well, first off I just want to say that you'll be much better off running Eclipse on your computer and transferring the compiled JAR to the Pi. Second, if you want a newer version than what's in the repository, you'll have to compile it yourself. I found [this post](https://resheim.net/2013/05/running-eclipse-rcp-applications-on.html) on how to do that, but that is for `armv6` and the Pi3 has an `armv8` chip so I don't know if it will work...